# mysqli equivalent of is_resource()

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm writing a database wrapper both in *mysql* and *mysqli*.

To get data via `fetch_object()` I've written a method:

```
public function fetch($mixed)
{
    if (is_resource($mixed))
    {
        return mysql_fetch_object($mixed);
    }
    elseif (!empty($mixed))
    {
        $result = $this->query($mixed);
        return mysql_fetch_object($result);
    }
    elseif (is_resource($this->result))
    {
        return mysql_fetch_object($this->result);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now I've heard that `is_resource()` is not a good solution for mysqli.

How else can I check if it is a *string* or an *mysqli_result*?

Comment: Sounds to me like your method is simply doing way too much. You should specify what the input and output of the function is. Having many different possible types of input leads to Great Ball Of Mud code.

Comment: There are already loads of DB wrappers out there, don't reinvent the wheel unless you really have to. On other note mysql_* functions are going to be deprecated very soon so use PDO and alternatives

Comment: @IvanHušnjak I disagree. Re-inventing the wheel is a great learning experience.

Comment: i want to use
`$result = $sql->query("SELECT id FROM table");
$data = $sql->fetch($result);`

and
`$data = $sql->fetch("SELECT id FROM table");`

Comment: @MikeB yes in school or to fiddle around, reinventing for purpose of real site - no

Comment: @TorbenL Using PDO object gives you same things: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> How else can I check if it is a string or an mysqli_result?

```
if (is_string($result)) { 
  // Result is a string
}

if ($result instanceof mysqli_result) {
  // Result is a mysqli_result object
}
```

Comment: For anyone who is not aware (like I was): If you check from inside another namespace, you must else prefix `mysqli_result` with a backslash `$result instanceof \mysqli_result`, or assign a variable to a string and use this for the check: `$classname = 'mysqli_result'; var_dump($result instanceof $classname);`